# Can't pull image from Azure Container Registry - pull denied

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-container-registry

I log in successfully, but cannot pull:

```
PS C:\Users\Me> docker login tlk8s.azurecr.io
Username (myUsername): Password:
Login Succeeded
PS C:\Users\Me> docker pull tlk8s.azurecr.io/devicecloudwebapi:v1
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for tlk8s.azurecr.io/devicecloudwebapi, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

But it seems like I'm naming it correctly (see screenshot):

[image]

What could I be doing wrong? How do I check to see if my service principal has the correct permissions?

Here's the result of calling Get-AzureRmRoleAssignment:

[image]

Comment: If you log in `tlk8s.azurecr.io` with the container register username and password? Or others? Most user can pull images. Some are limited.

Answer (score 4):

Per documentation below, the Service Principal account must have at least **Reader** role to be able to pull images from the Azure Container Registry.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication

You can run the following PS script to **list the existing role assignments** for your Service Principal account.

https://github.com/evandropaula/Azure/blob/master/ServicePrincipal/PS/List-ServicePrincipalRoleAssignments.ps1

You can run the following PS script to **assign a role** (e.g. Reader) to your Service Principal account.

https://github.com/evandropaula/Azure/blob/master/ServicePrincipal/PS/Assign-ServicePrincipalRole.ps1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I had contributor access, but my container registry was in a different resource group than my service principal. D'oh.

Comment: How did you solve this? We also have a case where we have AKS on different sub than ACR and we'd very much like to keep it that way.

Comment: @KimLindqvist Since I was just experimenting with it I was able to move everything over to one resource group. I'm not sure how to deal with multiple RGs.